# Requirement for explicit type conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion

For `static_cast`, Is it true that, unless there exist a built-in type conversion function, you cannot use `static_cast` to perform conversion. But you can do a `reinterpret_cast` for a type, considering the return type is valid.

```
int main()
{
    WORD word;
    HWND hwnd = static_cast<HWND>(word); // error
    HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(word); // ok, considering a valid handle is returned.
}
```

Do the explicit type conversions done with static_cast require a conversion function unlike reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Uhm... What's the question, specifically?

Comment: @Jason - When static_cast is an error, so is probably also the reinterpret_cast. The compiler will just not tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` just allows you to convert completely unrelated types. It just treats the chunk of memory as another type. So it is very unsafe to use it, since it just doesn't give you any compile or runtime errors but just causes (usually) crash

`static_cast` provides compile time check of validity of an cast. If an type cannot be treated as another type then `static_cast` gives you an compile time error when attempting an cast. 
It does implicit conversions between types (such as int to float, or pointer to void*), and it can also call explicit conversion functions (or implicit ones).

So you can say that it can do the implicit casts for which there is an implicit conversion inbuilt function present. It is usually considered as replacement for c-style casting if that is the confusion.

Comment: one thing forgot to tell is that `reinterpret_cast` guarantees that when you'll cast the type back to its original type , you'll get the same result

Comment: "The mapping performed by reinterpret_cast might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value." Only under certain circumstances is reinterpret_cast reliable. It should be avoided.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can `reinterpret_cast<int>(myfloat) != static_cast<int>(myfloat)`, provided `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, according to the specs?

Comment: @trinithis: Those are not even valid (i.e. should not compile).

Answer (score 0):

The C++ casts make most sense when casting pointers and references.

Concrete examples

```
void foo (Base & b) {
    if (b .is_a_Foo ())
        static_cast <Foo &> (b) .bar ();
    else
        b .do_default_bar ();
    dynamic_cast <Baz &> (b) .something (); // throws if invalid conversion
}

char data [4];
* reinterpret_cast <float *> (data) = 1.23;
```

The Windows API is a horrible hack from top to bottom -- in your example, reinterpret_cast is faithful to the original intent (and highlights it for the world to admire) and it basically means "throw away the type system and use the raw bits: trust me".

Answer (score 0):

Basically `static_cast` allocates memory for **compatible class** size of **destination** type and fills it with **what is possible**, but **without** any **checking** that new object is **complete**. Let me give you an example:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int c;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A;
    a->a = 5;
    B *b = new B;
    b->a = 6;
    b->b = 7;
    b->c = 8;

    B* bb = static_cast<B*>(a);
    A* aa = static_cast<A*>(b);

    cout << bb->a << endl; // 5
    cout << bb->b << endl; // scrap value from memory
    // member b was not initialized, because it was not found in A

    cout << aa->a << endl; // 6

    return 0;
}
```

In your example static cast is invalid, because `hwnd` is `void *` and `word` is `unsigned short`. For c++ casts any type can be considered as a class;

reinterpret_cast works **always**. It is just a binary copy